# Use author-year citations with thl3i.bst

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm currently writing my thesis on LyX 2.1 with the [template of Matthieu Perreira Da Silva](http://www.perreira.net/matthieu/telechargements/modele-de-these-lyx/). This uses the thl3i.bst bibliography template. The template is too big for me to paste the code here but it is in the zip file available following the [link](http://www.perreira.net/matthieu/telechargements/modele-de-these-lyx/).

Let's consider a reference **"NameA, NameB, 2001..."** that I want to cite. If I let all bibliography parameters as "implicit" in LyX, I get citations like **[NameA 01]**. However, I want it to be **[NameA et al. 2001]** and I don't know how to do that. I tried using natbib with "Author-year", but then I get a "*Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations*" error, while there is no year/author missing from my .bib file.

Is there a way to get the format I want?

Is there also a way to add new formats accessibles by LyX (I would prefer to use LyX's citation tool instead of LaTeX to make my citations)? I would like to add **"AuthorA et al. [2001]"** and **"AuthorA et al."** as I tend to use both when writing